# What's wrong with my systemd/system/my_service.service?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

Here is my service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=my_service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_scripts/script.sh
Restart=always
Type=simple
```

And here is /home/ubuntu/my_scripts/script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/my_app
cd /home/ubuntu/my_app
python /home/ubuntu/my_app/my_python_script.py
```

And when enter the command `/home/ubuntu/my_scripts/script.sh` in the terminal, it works well.

But it fails with the systemd service like this.

```
● my_service.service - my_service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_service.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-07-14 07:12:15 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 20713 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_scripts/script.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20713 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 14 07:12:15 ip-172-31-4-214 systemd[1]: my_service.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 14 07:12:15 ip-172-31-4-214 systemd[1]:my_service.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 14 07:12:15 ip-172-31-4-214 systemd[1]: Stopped job_executor.
Jul 14 07:12:15 ip-172-31-4-214 systemd[1]: my_service.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 14 07:12:15 ip-172-31-4-214 systemd[1]: my_service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 14 07:12:15 ip-172-31-4-214 systemd[1]: Failed to start my_service.
```

What's wrong?

---

Thnak you for the comments!
So I changed my service file into the below,

```
[Unit]
Description=my_service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_scripts/script.sh
Restart=always
Type=forking
```

Error message changed.

```
Job for my_service.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status my_service.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I typed `systemctl status my_service.service`

```
● my_service.service - my_service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_service.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-07-14 07:38:27 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 26815 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_scripts/script.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: `type` is missing in your service definition

Comment: @Panki Thank you, I edited it. But it still not working and error message was same.

Comment: Tip: your type is not `simple`, but `forking` - you call a script that calls other processes. And don't forget `systemctl daemon-reload` after changes.

Comment: Change it to `Type=forking` - this should fix it. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Service_types

Comment: @Panki @ Artem S. Tashkinov Thank you for the comments! I applied it, and error message changed and still not working...

Comment: Please ignore comment-answers about `forking`.  They illustrate why one should always take comment-answers with a large dose of salt.  If posted properly as actual answers, they would face the immediate criticism that the question nowhere provides information that anything in the service is doing fork-and-exit-parent.  Indeed, as is all too often the case with reports of systemd service problems, because it has used the default for `systemctl status` the question doesn't show potential answerers the parts of the log emitted by the actual service program, or where the service failed.